# cake php http GET with bearer key?

Tags: php, curl, get

Hi I'm using following code to send Https GET request to another api

```
        $access_token = $this->Session->read("AUTH_BEARER");
        $url = GET_DOCUMENT_BY_ID_URL.'202';

        $curl=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);// comment this line in live servers

        $response_json=curl_exec($curl);
        $error= curl_errno($curl);
        $error_message= curl_error($curl);
        echo "error:".$error;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Error message:".$error_message;
        echo "<br>";
        curl_close($curl);

        $response_array = json_decode($response_json,true);
        echo $response_json;
```

But I didn't receive any response from server. I make this call as soon as I receive bearer token, so I hope I made the call before token expire. what I'm doing wrong here? can someone help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.Note: I'm using https:// not http://

Answer (score 0):

nothing to do with cakephp here , if You only want to send GET request , you dont need to use curl , you can use file_get_contents like the following example

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?xxxx=112';
$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token
));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$webservice= file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $webservice;
```

Comment: here how can I set bearer token array("Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token)

Comment: check my answer i modified